# Cannot find symbol variable Red?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating APK by using Assemble release the **Android studio** produce error

```
 Error:(52, 86) error: cannot find symbol variable Red
```

while it work fine on debug. The line of code which produce this error is

```
spiner.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Does any guys meet this issue?Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try android.R.color.Red may be R is from your package like com.xyz.R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Red color code RED is not available in R.color.

Check this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

for your problem you may try

R.color.holo_red_dark

hope that will work for you.